Episode of Rugrats where Phil pushes Lil over and says it's because he likes her
This has been driving me crazy but I remember years ago watching an episode of Rugrats and Phil pushes Lil to the ground..
Lil responds with "why did you do that for?"
Phil replies "Cause I like ya"
I think it happens after them witnessing Angelica being mean to a boy she has a crush on but I'm not 100% on that.

You may have gotten it the other way around (understandable, they look alike). According to TVTropes, the episode is Cradle Attraction (season 3, ep 26):

"Cradle Attraction" when Chuckie discovers that the girl Megan picks on him because she likes him (read: has a crush). Lil shoves Phil and when he asks why she did it, she responds "it's because I like you" - and they both giggle.

